# Protobuf-net StackOverflowException with simple inheritance structure

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am working on a system that writes packets to a stream using protobuf-net, but I've run into an issue.

I've managed to distill the problematic code to this:

```
[TestFixture]
public static class ProtoTest {
    [ProtoContract]
    public class RootType {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public ChildBase child;
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(10, typeof(Child1))]
    [ProtoInclude(20, typeof(Child2))]
    public class ChildBase {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public int none;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Child1 : ChildBase {
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Child2 : ChildBase {
    }

    [Test]
    public static void Crashtest() {
        var root = new RootType();
        var writerStream = new MemoryStream();
        var readerStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new ProtoWriter(writerStream, RuntimeTypeModel.Default, new SerializationContext());
        var reader = new ProtoReader(readerStream, RuntimeTypeModel.Default, new SerializationContext());

        root.child = new Child1();
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize(writer, root);

        // Removing this line will allow the code to run properly
        root.child = new Child2();

        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize(writer, root);

        writerStream.WriteTo(readerStream);
        readerStream.Position = 0;

        // This call will produce the exception
        var firstChild = ((RootType)RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(reader, null, typeof(RootType))).child;

        Assert.NotNull(firstChild, "first child");
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Child1), firstChild.GetType());
        var secondChild = ((RootType)RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(reader, null, typeof(RootType))).child;
        Assert.NotNull(secondChild, "second child");
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Child2), secondChild.GetType());
    }
}
```

This will produce a `StackOverflowException` and crash the NUnit test runner.

`ChildBase` in this example would be the base class for my packets, and `RootType` the wrapper instance that is required by protobuf-net to remain constant.

1. Am I doing something silly here?
2. Do I have to write some kind of delimiter to the stream to separate the objects?
3. Is there a better way to write and read back packets of different types while allowing `AsReference` to work?

I would appreciate any insight you might have.

For reference, here is a slice of the stack at the time of the exception:

```
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(System.Type type, bool demand, bool getBaseKey) Line 718 + 0xffffffd4 bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKeyImpl(System.Type type) Line 711 + 0x10 bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.GetKey(ref System.Type type) Line 1224 + 0x10 bytes    C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter writer, object value) Line 183 + 0xc bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(System.IO.Stream dest, object value, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) Line 218 C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Merge(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader parent, object from, object to) Line 1337  C#
[Lightweight Function]  
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 57 + 0x1a bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 775 + 0xf bytes    C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader reader, System.Type type, object value, bool noAutoCreate) Line 700 + 0x14 bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) Line 589 + 0x14 bytes  C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type) Line 566 + 0x14 bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Merge(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader parent, object from, object to) Line 1338 + 0x13 bytes C#
[Lightweight Function]  
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 57 + 0x1a bytes C#
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) Line 775 + 0xf bytes    C#
....
```

Note, that I am running r668, since that's what I have the .pdb for, but the latest version will also produce an overflow.

Comment: oof; I'll need to find some time to pull that apart - inheritance ones are always fun... on the surface that looks OK, but...

Comment: Thank you. It's not a critical matter on my end, since I made a workaround that ensures there is only ever one `RootType` in the input stream. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: The code does not throw `StackOverflowException` any more